# Matrix quantization and effect on singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

Let $A$ and $B$ be an $N\times n$ matrix with $n\le N$, and let $\sigma_1(X),\dots \sigma_n(X)$ denote the singular values of $X\in \{A,B\}$. Do we have upper and lower bounds for
$$
\|
\sigma_i(A)-\sigma_i(B)
\|
$$
as a function of $\|A-B\|$ (for some matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$)?

Comment: No. $A=\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ have the same singular value, but $\|A-B\|\not= 0$.

Comment: Are there reasonable conditions on the involved matrices for which such bounds would be possible?

Comment: The singular values of $A$ are the eigenvalues of $A^*A$. Findung a bound on those eigenvalues will probably be easier.

Comment: @ABIM Upper bounds in terms of $\|A - B\|$ can be obtained, but as Christian's comment demonstrates lower bounds don't typically apply. One situation where a lower bound could be obtained is if it is known a priori that the highest singular value of $A$ is smaller than the smallest singular value of $B$ (or vice versa).

Comment: The singular values can also be obtained as the non-negative eigenvalues of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0 & A\\A^* & 0}.
$$
Often, this matrix is more convenient to use than $A^*A$ or $AA^*$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann In the case where $\sigma_1(A)\le \sigma_1(B)$ how would one get a bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Weyl's inequalities for singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_for_singular_values) give you the desired upper bound and, in some cases, a lower bound.

For the upper bound, we have
$$
|\sigma_i(A) - \sigma_i(B)| \leq \sigma_1(B - A) = \|B - A\|,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the spectral norm. This can easily be extended to other unitarily invariant norms.

For the lower bound, one situation where a lower bound is guaranteed is where
$\sigma_1(A) \leq \sigma_n(B)$. In this case,
we note using the variational characterization of singular values that
$$
\sigma_1(A) = \max_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\| \leq \min_{\|x\| = 1}\|Bx\| = \sigma_n(B)
$$
and that
$$
\begin{align}
\|B - A\| &= \sigma_1(B-A) = \max_{\|x\| = 1}(B - A)x
\\ & \geq \max_{\|x\| = 1} (\|Bx\| - \|Ax\|)
\\ & \geq \min_{\|x\| = 1}\|Bx\| - \max_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\| = \sigma_n(B) - \sigma_1(A),
\end{align}
$$
so that $\sigma_n(B) - \sigma_1(A) \geq \|B - A\|$. From there, it follows that for all $i$ $\sigma_n(B) \leq \sigma_i(B)$ and $\sigma_1(A) \geq \sigma_i(A)$, so that
$$
\sigma_i(B) - \sigma_i(A) \geq \sigma_n(B) - \sigma_1(A) \geq \|B - A\|.
$$

I suspect that this can be extended to other unitarily invariant norms without too much trouble.